# How to load JSON file dynamically on react app

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I want to load a JSON settings file dynamically in my react application.

I'm using webpack and when I `import` the file like:

```
import appSettings from './appSettings.json';
```

Or require it:

```
const appSettings = require('./appSettings.json');
```

It compiles the json and not load it dynamically (e.g. not changeable during runtime).

Can someone assist ?

Comment: Is your file path correct?

Comment: It is. if not - I wouldn't get data

Comment: Check our @Nkubito Pacis' answer. Does it help?

Comment: I'm not sure if React is really designed to handle this.  Why are you writing changes to a JSON text file rather than making changes in a settings state?  It would make more sense to use the state as your single source of truth and push changes to file based on the state rather than the other way around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At last, what I did is loading the file with axios in the root of my app.

```
  const [appSettings, setAppSettings] = React.useState<any>(null);
  React.useEffect(() => {
    axios.get('./appSettings.json').then((response: any) => {
      setAppSettings(response.data);
    });
  }, [appSettings && appSettings.data]);

  return (
    appSettings &&
    appSettings.baseUrl && (
      <Layout className={styles.root}>
        <MyApp appSettings={appSettings} />
      </Layout>
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

You should consider adding useEffect hook so that it re-renders your page when there is a change in the json

```
    import appSettings from './appSettings.json';
    import {useEffect} from 'react';
    useEffect(()=>{
       //code to run whe the json has loaded   
},[appSettings])
```

Comment: Will that work?  I think the imports are only loaded once when the file is first run.